# Biztalk WCF-Custom Adapter gives time out error

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I am running a stored procedure on SQL Azure Database using BizTalk WCF-Custom adapter. I have around 20k records to be processed as composite operation. We are using BizTalk 2013 R2 on Windows Server 2012.

I am getting following error after 40-50 minutes:

> A message sent to adapter "WCF-Custom" on send port
>   "Swire.BizTalk.M3.Send.PushAssets.Local" with URI
>   "mssql://xngoo0zsw2.database.windows.net//overvuuat_20150720?" is
>   suspended.   Error details:
>   Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.InvalidUriException: Timeout
>   expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection
>   from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections
>   were in use and max pool size was reached. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period
>   elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have
>   occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size
>   was reached.    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   Microsoft.Adapters.Sql.SqlAdapterConnection.OpenConnection()    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action,
>   Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.RequestCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)   MessageId:  {9034380A-E116-4694-BD70-F9933BF37BD3}
>   InstanceID: {91B6E1AA-32AD-48D9-A18A-F9BF20529764}

Following are configurations for that send port:

[image]

I increased the timeout from 00:50:00 to 05:00:00 but no change in result. still getting same error.

I run `SP_WHO2` to get the list of connection those are running/queued. There were more than 100+ connection when the error raised. One of the query "Select Into" was in suspend mode and displayed as it was running from SSMS. but we have no such query and we never run any query from directly from SSMS.

Please suggest a way to resolve this.

Comment: can you show us a screenshot of the general tab ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are hitting the maxConnectionPoolSize which is 100 and increasing the timeout wouldn't help in this case. You can use non-pooled connections but before going that see why there are 100+ connections to the database. This could be because of the performance issues on the database (may need to scale) / application issues (locks being held on the table and blocking other queries or connections aren't closed so none of them are returned back to pool).

For performance issues, query sys.resource_stats to see whether your database resource utilization is peaking. Also you can use sys.dm_Exec_Requests and sys.dm_tran_locks to see what other connections are doing. I believe you are closing the connections in your app when you are done using them (otherwise they won't return back to pool)